# How do I simply name a row heading in sas

Tags: sas

All I would like to do is name each row in the output of this simple cluster algorithm. For example instead of row 1, 2, 3, and 4 have best, good, bad, and worst. Thanks!

```
proc fastclus data=tdriv.nfl2015 maxclus=4 out=clus;
var OffptsPerG DefPtsPerG;
run;
```

Comment: Just tried this and unfortunately it doesn't work, or I'm probably formatting it incorrectly. I'm very new to SAS.

Answer (score 2):

SAS doesn't have the concept of 'row header'.  However, if you have a variable with values 1,2,3,4 (which you will - the cluster value!), you can use a format to do so.

```
proc format;
  value clusf
    1='Best'
    2='Good'
    3='Bad'
    4='Worst'
  ;
quit;

proc datasets lib=work;
  modify clus;
  format cluster CLUSF.;
quit;
```

This assumes that you can reliably link 1,2,3,4 to those four values; I'm not sure FASTCLUS is reliable in that way.  If it's not, you may have to code this afterwards by hand and/or use code to determine which cluster is which.

Answer (score 1):

Joe's approach seems reasonable... Here's another one. Haven't tested it having no data to test with, but here it goes:

After running your proc fastclus, modify the output dataset, adding a variable which will serve as ID in a future proc print:

```
data clus;
  format position $8.;
  set clus;
  if cluster=1 then position="Best";
  else if cluster=2 then position="Good";
  /* ... and so on ... */
run;
```

And then when printing:

```
proc print data=clus;
  id position;
run;
```